# How to use useAnimatedRef with RecylerListView?

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated-v2, recyclerlistview

I am working with [RecylerListView](https://github.com/Flipkart/recyclerlistview) because I have a large list. I want to [useAnimatedRef](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/api/hooks/useAnimatedRef/) from react-native-reanimated2 to enable synchronous ScrollTo actions. However, when I add it as a Ref, it doesn't work and tells me that ScrollTo is not defined.

```
 const animatedRecyclerRef = useAnimatedRef()


if(animatedRecyclerRef?.current){
       animatedRecyclerRef.current.scrollTo({ x:0, y:200 });
}

<RecyclerListView
        ref={animatedRecyclerRef}
        rowRenderer={rowRenderer}
        dataProvider={dataProvider}
        layoutProvider={layoutProvider}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your own scrollview to recyclerlistview using `externalScrollView` prop. You should be able to grab a ref to that instead.